# Trouble understanding path-connected components of the topological space C(X,Y)

Tags: calculus, general-topology, connectedness

$C(X,Y)$ is the set of all continuous functions from topological space $X$ to topological space $Y$. I'm trying to prove this theorem:

If $X$ is locally compact, two functions $f,g \in C(X,Y)$ are in the same path-connected component $\iff$ there exists a continuous $H[0,1] \times X \rightarrow Y$ s.t. for every $x \in X$ we have $H(0,x) = f(x)$ and $H(1,x) = g(x)$.

The way I see it, both sides seem to be trivial. If such an $H$ exists, then that is the path that connects two elements, therefore they're in the same component. If they're in the same component, such an $H$ has to exist.

Obviously I'm wrong, but I cannot seem to figure out where. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which topology do you consider on $C(X,Y)$?

Comment: The topology isn't specified in the question. I would assume this is correct for all topologies on C(X,Y).

Comment: Surely not, If we take e.g. $X = Y = [0,1]$ with the standard topology, all continuous functions $X\to Y$ are homotopic, but there are topologies on $C(X,Y)$ under which it is disconnected. _Probably_ the topology considered on $C(X,Y)$ is the compact-open topology, but I want to make sure.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, Daniel is right, the topology is the compact-open topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially you have the right idea, but there are some subtleties
with respect to continuity.

I do not think I can explain those issues any clearer
than Ralph H. Fox already did in 1945, so I will just refer you to
*[On topologies for function spaces](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1945-08370-0)*.